# Doubts on what association to choose

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner Rails developer and right now am building a sample project to show off at some job apply. The app is rather simple, I guess, but I have come to some doubts on what associations to chose and why.

Basically a User can create a bill(being its creditor) and the billing can have many other Users(as their debtors), so you can track up billings you share with other persons, like rent, market, food orders etc, and control what each one got to pay you.

Right now I have the following model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :billings, foreign_key: "creditor_id", dependent: :destroy
    has_many :debts, foreign_key: "debtor_id", dependent: :destroy
end

class Billing < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :creditor, class_name: "User"
    has_many :debts, dependent: :destroy
end

class Debt < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :billing
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Would this be the better approach? Or something like:
User has_many billings through debts
Billing has_many debts ?

And in that case, would appreciate some help to model those associations, because I'm still kinda lost on this flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a single creditor and multiple debtors for a single billing, you will need a one to one relationship for the creditor -> billing (belongs_to on the billing, as you have done), but a many to many relationship for debts -> users.

Generally, it's better to implement the many-to-many as a has_many :through so you can add logic. It's probably doubly important when there is money involved!

I would rethink the dependent: destroy though. You probably want to use a soft delete instead, or else you will lose your past transactions.